# How To Simplify Object Key ReUse

Tags: javascript, optimization, refactoring

My app's navigation module needs me to provide a **route name** for each screen in the navigation stack.
Previously I used clean, strings like `Sign In`, `Overview`, `Sign Up`, etc.

The header shown on each screen needs a title to display, so I simply showed the **route name** of the current screen as the title. *Easy*.

The time has come now for me to add more languages to my app; I figured I could fix this with the following approach:

```js
// routeNames.js

export const routeNames = { 
  overviewMainScreen: 'overviewMainScreen' 
  // ...
};
```

```js
// translationEnUs.js

import { routeNames } from './routeNames.js';

export default {
  [routeNames.overviewMainScreen]: 'Overview' 
  // ...
};
```

```js
// translationFrFr.js

import { routeNames } from './routeNames.js';

export default {
  [routeNames.overviewMainScreen]: 'Aperçu' 
  // ...
};
```

My translation utility expects a key that it uses to look up the translated string in the language dictionaries I provide (such as `screenTitleTranslationEnUs` and `screenTitleTranslationFrFr`).

Something like:

```js
// app.js

const routeName = this.navigationModule.currentRouteName;
// "overviewMainScreen"

// let's say the current language is French
const screenHeaderTitle = translateHook(routeName);
// Aperçu

// ...
```

---

---

The way I've done it now seems a bit convoluted to me, as it would make me stumble if I encountered it in someone else's code. Any better data structure I can use to get the same result, or a smarter/simpler technique I can use?

Comment: Don't use bunches of standalone variables - use a single object indexed by a language string instead

Comment: I... do not know what that means, I'm sorry

Comment: Eg `screenTitleTranslationEnUs` is a standalone variable

Comment: Aah, the reason I have it in that format is I keep translations for each language in their own file. I don't want to end up with a 500 line file of translations down the road as the app grows.

Comment: @Will the solution is usually to have one file per hanguage. All should have the same structure, so you'd have `translations-en-US.json`, `translations-en-GB.json`, `translation-fr-FR.json`, `translation-fr-BE.json`, etc. (or put them in a database, whatever). When loading the translations you *chain* several to provide fallback translations and *merge and override* all values with whatever is supplied in more relevant files. E.g., if want to have UK specific overriding, you load `en-US` -> `en-GB` with `vehicle.truck = "truck"` for US but `vehicle.truck = "lorry"` in the UK but leave the rest

Comment: I updated the question to better reflect the state of the code